# Why do I need to place car cabin filter according Air flow label

Tags: car

in most of car cabin filters (for example MANN filter) I see that I need to place it according the "Air flow" label? 
But why I need to do that? 
What will be wrong if I will put it in opposite side of "Air flow" label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually because the strengthening in the filter is optimised for one direction and the layers may also be optimised so the oncoming air is met with a coarse layer first, followed by successively finer layers.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense. It is much more clear for me now.

Comment: filters of that type are called "through" filters; they rely on the graded density increase to maintain flow while capturing the particulates and also to safely entrain as much material as possible before the filter becomes unserviceably plugged with stuff.

Comment: Are there another types of cabin filters?

Comment: Simple, pollen then HEPA

Comment: Thanks and what type of filter described in answer?

Comment: You can have a simple cotton or gauze filter, then carbon particle, activated carbon particle, pollen filters are finer then hepa are the most effective... The manufacturer may proffered several levels or types, or may not and only specify one...